# T-SQL Search and replace pattern

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

My brain just isn't working today. I have a string that has a comma separated list of email addresses similar to below

> removethis<removethis@xx.com>; andthis<andthis@xx.com>; nothis@yy.com; butthis<butthis@xx.com>

I would like to just return a semicolon separated list of email address so the output I am looking for would be something like this

removethis@xx.com;andthis@xx.com;nothis@yy.com;butthis@xx.com

I would like to achieve this in a T-SQL function so I can reuse this if possible.

The list that gets passed as seen in example above can either be just an email address or a name followed by email between. The logic needs to check if it's just an email then return it, if it's a name and an email (indicated by pattern name **<** email **>** then just return what's between the <>

for info: SQL version: Azure SQL Database

Example scenario:

```
DECLARE @X varchar(max) = '
removethis<removethis@xx.com>;andthis<andthis@xx.com>;nothis@yy.com;butthis<butthis@xx.com>'
Select @udfFormatEmail(@X)
```

Expected output:

> removethis@xx.com;andthis@xx.com;nothis@yy.com;butthis@xx.com

Comment: Don't do this in T-SQL; use something that supports regex replacement (or "invest" in a CLR function that does).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @Larnu - I am limited to what I can use with this solution but yes, I agree would be easier with another technology

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - details are already in the call - technology - Azure SQL, reproduceable example provided at the end of the question with expected output

Comment: @user7415753, please provide explicitly ##1-4. "...I have a string that has a comma separated list of email addresses in a SQL server table column...". where is it?

Comment: Thank you @YitzhakKhabinsky. I have edited the question for clarification for any future people checking the question and removed the in a SQL column. I believe the question does have all the necessary information now to reproduce and the two answers already submitted have demonstrated that. Will keep your comment for reference for any future posts. Appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a combination of `string_split` and `string_agg` and `stuff` to remove all the characters before each '<'.

```
declare @X varchar(max) ='removethis<removethis@xx.com>;andthis<andthis@xx.com>;nothis@yy.com;butthis<butthis@xx.com>'

select String_Agg(Replace(Stuff(value,1, CharIndex('<',value),''),'>',''),';')
from String_Split(@X,';')
```

Answer (score 2):

**You really should not store multiple pieces of info in the same column**, this applies both to multiple emails, and to the email name and value.

Be that as it may, you can do this in a number of steps:

- Split the string by `;`
- Trim spaces
- Replace the `>` with nothing
- Find the position of `<` if any
- Take the substring starting the character after that, or the whole string if none
- Aggregate it back up

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(
    ISNULL(
        SUBSTRING(v1.email, v2.leftArrow + 1, LEN(v1.email)),
        v1.email
   ), ';')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.emails, ';') s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (REPLACE(TRIM(s.value), '>', '')     )) v1(email)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('<', v1.email), 0) )) v2(leftArrow)
```

Comment: I like this answer but accepted Stu's answer as it provided an easier way of achieving what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It leverages advanced functionality of the `TRIM()` function that became available staring from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, emailList VARCHAR(MAX));  
INSERT INTO @tbl (emailList) VALUES
('removethis<removethis@xx.com>; andthis<andthis@xx.com>; nothis@yy.com; butthis<butthis@xx.com>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT a.emailList
    , STRING_AGG(TRIM('<> ' FROM RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - pos)), ';') AS cleansedEmailList
FROM @tbl AS a
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(emailList, ';')
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('<', value)) AS t(pos)
GROUP BY a.emailList;
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                           emailList                                            |                       cleansedEmailList                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| removethis<removethis@xx.com>; andthis<andthis@xx.com>; nothis@yy.com; butthis<butthis@xx.com> | removethis@xx.com;andthis@xx.com;nothis@yy.com;butthis@xx.com |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```